# Is it possible to open a google map url into an external web browser?

Tags: android, google-maps, webbrowser-control

Is it possible to open a google map url with latlng values into an external web browser?

Currently I have used simple Intent but it open into Google map, Please help me if it possible.

Comment: Show us some code and tell us exactly what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:23.070791,72.520004";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
        startActivity(intent);
```

I hope this will helpful